# Drawing a line that's always as wide as its parent BoxElement?

Tags: javascript, node.js, tui, blessed

I'm using a `BoxElement` from [blessed](https://www.npmjs.com/package/blessed) to display a chat history.

Sentences are added using `pushLine`. For clarity, days are divided by lines (another string added using `pushLine`). Each line is as wide as the parent `BoxElement`.

If the TUI is resized however, the line no longer fits.

I have 2 questions:

1. How can that line adapt to its new width?
2. (bonus points) How can I center text in the middle of that line?

An example of the issue is shown below:

```
/**
 * Example.ts
 */
import * as blessed from 'blessed';

const screen = blessed.screen({
    smartCSR: true,
    title: 'Chatr',
    dockBorders: true
});

const chatBox = blessed.box({
    parent: screen,
    title: 'Chatbox',
    top: 'top',
    left: 'center',
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%',
    border: {
        type: 'line'
    },
});
screen.append(chatBox);
screen.render();

chatBox.pushLine("This is the first line");

 // This is the separator - and will not resize with the terminal 
chatBox.pushLine("_".repeat(chatBox.width as number - 2));

chatBox.pushLine("This is a second line");
screen.render();
```

When the code is run `ts-node ./Example.js` it renders this:

```
┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│This is a line                                                                          │
│________________________________________________________________________________________│
│This is a second line                                                                   │
│                                                                                        │
│                                                                                        │
│                                                                                        │
│                                                                                        │
│                                                                                        │
│                                                                                        │
│                                                                                        │
│                                                                                        │
│                                                                                        │
│                                                                                        │
│                                                                                        │
│                                                                                        │
│                                                                                        │
│                                                                                        │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Resizing the terminal gets this result:

```
┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│This is a line                                            │
│__________________________________________________________│
│______________________________                            │
│This is a second line                                     │
│                                                          │
│                                                          │
│                                                          │
│                                                          │
│                                                          │
│                                                          │
│                                                          │
│                                                          │
│                                                          │
│                                                          │
│                                                          │
│                                                          │
│                                                          │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal reproducible example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems `blessed` doesn't implement something like a separator, but we can simply implement them by ourselves with a simple class which stores the line index of each separator and change them on `resize` event. Something like:

```
import * as blessed from "blessed";

// The required Separators class
class Separators {
  private box: any;
  private separators: number[] = [];

  public constructor(box: any) {
    this.box = box;

    box.on("resize", () => {
      const sep = this.sep();

      this.separators.forEach(line => {
        box.deleteLine(line);
        box.insertLine(line, sep);
      });
    });
  }

  public add(): void {
    const { box, separators } = this;

    separators.push(box.getLines().length);
    box.pushLine(this.sep());
  }

  private sep(): string {
    return "_".repeat((this.box.width as number) - 3);
  }
}

const screen = blessed.screen({
  smartCSR: true,
  title: "Chatr",
  dockBorders: true
});

const chatBox = blessed.box({
  parent: screen,
  title: "Chatbox",
  top: "top",
  left: "center",
  height: "100%",
  width: "100%",
  border: {
    type: "line"
  }
});
const sep = new Separators(chatBox); // <- the new Separator bound to the box
screen.append(chatBox);
screen.render();

chatBox.pushLine("This is the first line");

// This is the separator - and it resize with the terminal
sep.add();

chatBox.pushLine("This is a second line");
chatBox.pushLine("While this is the third line");

// This is another separator - it resize with the terminal as well
sep.add();

chatBox.pushLine("And last this is the last line");

screen.render();
```

About the bonus point, now it should be quite easy to achieve it; the hard part is to center a line longer than the box width: if we split it in more lines to center, all the line indexes (next to split centered line) will changes and could become harder to keep track of them.

A possible compromise could be to accept to center only lines shorter than box width, left padding them with the right amount of spaces.